# Why ASP.NET MVC Application is Unwantedly Loading Bootstrap Multiple Times

Tags: c#, css, asp.net-mvc, twitter-bootstrap, asp.net-mvc-5

My ASP.NET MVC 5 application is too heavy due to the application loading bootstrap and other CSS files unwantedly too many times.
**How do you fix this?**

Here's a screenshot of a fresh new ASP.NET MVC 5 Project:

[image]

On the screenshot you'll see that bootstrap.css has been loaded 9 times. Causing the page to be of total of 1,596.68 KB!

This happens to all my projects even if its fresh (no edits).

I hope you've come across this problem and have an idea how to fix it. Or is it a bug? Anyways, my IDE is Visual Studio 2013 Web Express with Update 4

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This link seems to suggest that it is a bug with Firefox developer tools: https://bugzilla.mozilla.org/show_bug.cgi?id=978688

The suggested solutions is to upgrade the browser and do a cache reset, even though your projects are fresh, the css-files might be cached since before.

Comment: Thanks! I didn't realize it could be the web browser's problem as my Firefox says it's still up-to-date (36.0.3). When I tried to run my ASP.NET MVC applications in Google Chrome, they were working fine as expected. I hope Firefox get's an update for this problem soon.